# "Undefined reference to"-error / static member var in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

First of all, I'm not really familiar with `C++/Qt`, so I tried it, as i would do it in `C#`... I also have some problems with pointers..

**The story:** I use the `QSerialPort` to read and write on a serial 232 port. Of course, there should be only one instance, otherwise there would be access errors. So my idea was to define a static member variable to hold the object.

**The problem:** I always get the error "undefined reference to `SerialManager::obj`"

**The source code:**

*serialmanager.h*

```
#include <QSerialPort>
class SerialManager
{
public:
    static QSerialPort* getObj();
private:
    static QSerialPort* obj;
}
```

*serialmanager.cpp*

```
#include "serialmanager.h"
QSerialPort *obj = new QSerialPort();

QSerialPort* SerialManager::getObj()
{
    if(!obj->isOpen())
    {
        obj->setPortName("/dev/ttyO1"); //error line
        obj->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud57600);
        //and so on...
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: You have the answer below. By the way, if you need only one instance, you can just create one instance and get rid of the static variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header file, you are declaring `SerialManager::obj` in the header file.

In your implementation file, you are defining `obj`, not`SerialManager::obj`.

The fix is to change

```
QSerialPort *obj = new QSerialPort();
```

to

```
QSerialPort *SerialManager::obj = new QSerialPort();
```

You may find you want to initialise it to `nullptr`, and construct on demand when you need it (that might solve problems with dependencies, and/or improve program start times, if you have many static objects to construct).

If you really want to only ever construct a single object, you could also make the pointer (but not the pointed-to object) constant:

```
private:
    static QSerialPort *const obj;
```

That can safeguard against accidentally assigning again (but can make it hard to substitute a different object for your unit tests).

Comment: Thanks too! Also because of the advise with the nullptr

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the class's name, fix it by changing

```
QSerialPort *obj = new QSerialPort();
```

into

```
QSerialPort *SerialManager::obj = new QSerialPort();
```

Comment: But C# is not different in this regard, as far as I can tell, except that the scope delimiter is `.` instead of `::`. Am I wrong?